# How to get specific part of a strings from a string using php?

Tags: php

I have a RGBA color in this format:

```
RGBA:1.000000,0.003922,0.003922,0.003922
```

How can I separate each value from this string such as:

```
var alpha = 1.000000;
var red = 0.003922;
var green = 0.003922;
var blue = 0.003922;
```

I want to do this in php.

Comment: What's your approach?

Comment: You can use split(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Comment: Try PHP [Explode function](http://us1.php.net/explode)

Comment: @sanketh: Don't use `split()`. It's deprecated. Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string into two parts with `:` as the delimiter, take the second part, and split the result again with `,` as the delimiter. Assign the values to variables. All this could be done in one line, as follows:

```
list($alpha, $red, $green, $blue) = explode(',', explode(':', $str, 2)[1]);
```

Output:

```
string(8) "1.000000"
string(8) "0.003922"
string(8) "0.003922"
string(8) "0.003922
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/135088)

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet should be like this:

```
$rgba = "1.000000,0.003922,0.003922,0.003922";
$rgba = explode(',', $rgba);
list($red, $green, $blue, $alpha) = $rgba;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using regex is

```
$str = 'RGBA:1.000000,0.003922,0.003922,0.003922';
preg_match_all("/(\d+\.+\d+)/", $str, $output_array);

list($alpha, $red, $green, $blue) = $output_array[1] ;
```

https://eval.in/135090